# Encounter Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

i encounter a problem and i need a help here is my

```
public function compare_cookie_count($cookie_condition, $ip ,$user_id ,$cid)
{
    $this->db->select('machine_id,cookie')
             ->from('cookie_monster_mode')
             ->where('machine_id', $ip)
             ->where('cookie',$cookie_condition)
             ->where('vote_id',$user_id)
             ->where('contest_id',$cid);

    return $this->db->get()->num_rows();
CODEIGNITER
}
```

i encounter this error  Trying to get property of non-object how can i fix it

Comment: Please report full error message, including line number [and outlining it in the question].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

num_rows returns the number of rows returned by the `query` (query result object).

So you should try

```
$query = $this->db->select('machine_id,cookie')
             ->from('cookie_monster_mode')
             ->where('machine_id', $ip)
             ->where('cookie',$cookie_condition)
             ->where('vote_id',$user_id)
             ->where('contest_id',$cid)
             ->get(); 
return $query->num_rows();
```

or like

```
return $this->db->select('machine_id,cookie')
                 ->from('cookie_monster_mode')
                 ->where('machine_id', $ip)
                 ->where('cookie',$cookie_condition)
                 ->where('vote_id',$user_id)
                 ->where('contest_id',$cid)
                 ->get()->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be saving the result from your first line and calling `num_rows()` on that.